# \tag is not allowed in eqnarray

Tags: amsmath, eqnarray, tag

I used \tag{} in eqnarray. But is not permitted and have an error "! Package amsmath Error: \tag not allowed here". Is there a solution to this? Please do as necessary after checking.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. I suggest that you [don't use `eqnarray`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196/134805).

Comment: `\tag` is a pure `AMSmath` tag, better switch from `eqnarray` to `align`

Answer (score 2):

You asked,

> Is there a solution to this?

Short answer: Yes.

Slightly longer answer: [Don't use `eqnarray` environments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196/5001). Instead, be sure to load the `amsmath` package and to use `align` environments.

Incidentally, `\tag` and `\notag` are macros that are provided by the `amsmath` package -- the very same package that defines the `align` environment. By design, there is no way to use them inside `eqnarray` environments.